# Flutter- record audio even after leaving the app

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

I am building an app where an user can start recording the audio of a session and the recording should continue till he clicks the stop button, even if leaves the app in between. A google search gave me plugins like flutter_sound but it isn't explicitly mentioned if it would allow recording the audio even if one leaves the app. So is there any package which can help me achieve the same? if not is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Though its not a good practice to keep the recorder on when the app is exited, just to give you an answer, you can try [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager)

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task) {
    //Write codes to record here
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

Workmanager.initialize(
    callbackDispatcher, //the top level function.
    isInDebugMode: true //If enabled it will post a notification whenever the job is running. Handy for debugging jobs
)
```

And to cancel it you can add a delay and call

```
Workmanager().cancelByTag("tag")
```

Comment: Okay, so do we use the Workmanager.initialize(....) statement when we want to start the recording, i.e in the onPress of the button?

Comment: Yeah and work manager will handle it. But make sure you stop recording after sometime. Maybe after 30 seconds. So onbutton press you can also run a Future.delayed of 30 seconds and return true from inside the future and stop the recording too.